# How to create discincts JS methodes in Spotify App

Tags: javascript, api, spotify, spotify-app

I've been working on a small Spotify app for some time now. I started using the old API (0.x) but now that I want to access the user's playlists, I need to use the library module which is only available throught the [API version 1.0](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/)

The spotify team even gives a [migration guide](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/upgrade-guide/1.0.0) to do so ! (if you read me: Thanks guys for all this ;) ).

I already have created a few objects (It's a small app so I don't need much more than that), with a function for each one of my needs, like so:

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi();
var models = require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
var player =  models.player;
var views = require('sp://import/scripts/api/views');

// in file 'mySpotify.js'
var mySpotify =
{
  playerNextTrack: function()
  {
    player.next();
  },
}
```

Whenever I need to Skip the current track, I can call `mySpotify.playerNextTrack();`

But now, with the new API, I need to do things like this (from [Spotify doc](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/global.html#require)):

```
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {
  var player = models.player;
  player.next();
});
```

My question is simple: how can I include this kind of code into my objects ? How can I give a name to this last "function" ?

As I'm fresh new to JS, I'm probably doing something wrong or understood something the wrong way so feel free to elaborate if you can ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with what I think is the easy answer, just put the `require([], function {[all your code]});` around your whole myspotify.js file.  That's basically what I have for mine, though I haven't built any of my own objects.  Don't think that would matter.

*Update*
Here's a bit more info showing that objects can be used.  Is this what you were looking for?

```
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {
var mySpotify =
{
  playerNextTrack: function()
  {
    models.player.skipToNextTrack();
  },
}

var playtest = document.querySelector('#playtest');
playtest.addEventListener('click', function() { mySpotify.playerNextTrack(); });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (sorry for the late response, I was away...)
I can't check if this works for now, but I will try this week.
No offence, but it looks to me that this is kind of a "workaround", isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry about that, but, could you show me a simplified version of what you have on your implementation ?
I tried to do something like this
`
    require(['$api/models'], function(model) {
      var ZmSpotify =
      {
      var player = models.player;
      player.next();
      });`

...but I've got a `Missing callback function argument to require()` in core.js :/

Comment: and I'm also sorry about this question format: SO doesn't allow me to use the 'code' format in here :(

Comment: Of course I don't know what your existing code looks like, but you can declare functions inside other functions. So your whole app can be inside the function of the require statement. Will try to flesh out my answer when I get to a computer later

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late: I had loads of work.
As you probably know, Spotify recently [suspended their 'web' apps program](https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2014/03/24/closure-of-spotify-apps-submissions/) so I no longer work on this subject.
Thanks for your help though ;)